# Spamassassin - Whitelist Domain A to Domain B

Tags: postfix, spamassassin, whitelist

I want to whitelist certain domains in spamassassin only if the recipient is also in a specific domain. As far as I can tell from the documentation, there seems to be no way to configure this requirement:

- Sender@Domain.one sends mail to Recipient@Domain.two -> Spamassassin should whitelist this mail
- Sender@Domain.one sends mail to other recipients (also on the same server, but different domain) -> Spamassassin should check the mail before forwarding it to the recipient

I've already added `whitelist_from *@domain.one` in my spamassassin config but this is a little to widely for my perception. The recipients domain should be whitelistet (everyone in Domain.two).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are Sender@Domain.one, you can do this. You can white-list e-mails towards Recipient@Domain.two and let the other ones get scanned. This is called white-listing a destination (outgoing ACL white-list).

If you are not Sender@Domain.one, you can't do what you state in the title. Filtering works for source (you) and destination (others), there is not way to interfere between 2 others.

If you are some kind of proxy, then you can white-list Sender@Domain.one on incoming and Recipient@Domain.two on outgoing and it should work.

Comment: Sadly I am Admin@Domain.three - so I need to regulate mail flow from a third party to our customer. Since our server is a multi-domain mailserver, and forwards the messages to our customers exchange, I'd like to have the rule only for the third parties mails to our customer (and not anyone else - which is allowed by the workaround rule I set). Thanks for taking the time to answer - I already thought this will be not possible. If no other miracle answer turns up, I will mark yours as correct :-)

Comment: If you are a proxy for the mail exchange between the two than see my updated answer. As a 3rd party server that is not proxy there's nothing you can do; the correct configurations can be done only on the target domain servers.

Comment: Actually we have a single server that handles incoming mail and redirects it to the customers exchange (or postfix, whatever). So I believe our options are very limited - either whitelisting recipient domain and therefore killing all of spamassassins use with it, or living with whitelisting the third party messages for all our hosted domains. Thanks for elaborating!